# Hibernate leaves me with blank screen after switching on on Linux Mint - what could have happened?

Tags: linux-mint, hibernate

I had left my computer to do some operations while I went to do something else. I had forgotten to put the charging plug in, and it died and hibernated. When I tried turning it back on, hibernating left me with a blank black screen and I had to force shut it down and completely reboot my Linux Mint 17.2. So, my questions are:

1. Why couldn't hibernate successfully restore my session?
2. Might any damage have been done to my system in the process of trying to restore a hibernation but not succeeding?

Answer (score 0):

This is more probably a hardware problem, or a compatibility problem between your hardware and the Linux kernel, than a distribution problem.

I had a similar problem with an older computer running Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 14.04, it seems to be mostly gone in a newer computer running 15.10 (when it happens I shut the screen to put the computer to sleep again and get my screen back when I open it up again). I've not kept the exact reference of the video card . . .

My problem was that the screen brightness was not correctly set when waking up. For some reason the screen brightness keys did not work. I was able to log in remotely and

```
echo 187 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

I would have liked to find some special SysBrk key to reset brightness to maximum, but I didn't find any, maybe because it's specific to Intel cards.

Therefore, it is important to know whether the kernel was "alive" (caps lock light, CD eject key...). If it is, it may be a video problem. If the kernel is dead, the problem is probably between the kernel and the ACPI hardware.